# Power BI REST API - POST a new PUSH Dataset

Tags: powershell, powerbi, rest

I am trying to programmatically create a new PUSH dataset in the PowerBI service and while I am able to authenticate properly and create the dataset with my specified "name", I am unable to create the dataset as a PUSH dataset with given fields/datatypes. I am using Powershell in this scenario.

Article referenced: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets/datasets-post-dataset#createdatasetrequest

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$body = '{
  "name": "DylanTest",
  "defaultMode": "Push",
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "Product",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "ProductID",
          "dataType": "Int64"
        },
        {
          "name": "Name",
          "dataType": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/myWorkspaceId/datasets?defaultRetentionPolicy=basicFIFO' -Method Post -Body $body
```

Response:

```
Environment : Public
TenantId    : myTenantId
UserName    : myUsername

{
  "@odata.context":"http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/myWorkspaceId/$metadata#datasets/$entity","id":"notSureWhatIdThisIs","name":"DylanTest","defaultRetentionPolicy":"BasicFIFO","targetStorageMode":"Unknown","upstre
amDatasets":[
    
  ],"schemaMayNotBeUpToDate":false,"users":[
    
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to create it? The response looks like it was created. What is the value of `addRowsAPIEnabled` when you call [Get Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-dataset) for the newly created dataset? If it is `true`, then this is a Push dataset.

Comment: I figured it out. I was confusing "Push" with "PushStreaming" as I wanted a streaming dataset, but did not realize they were separate options.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to switch from "Push" to "PushStreaming" in the body request. I was confusing the two different types of datasets so I thought the request was not sending the body properly.